# Why can't Visual Studio 2012 format this valid Razor code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, razor

So I have some valid Razor syntax code in a view that builds and runs fine. However, in Visual Studio 2012, the code will not format correctly, Razor seems "fragile" in parsing this document and when I auto format the code CTRL + K + D. Some the content floats left, ugly, not formatting to the nested parent-child structure. I cannot add a `@` to my second if condition which could fix the floating left HTML content.

```
@foreach (var customField in Model.CustomFields)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @customField.label
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-md-4 padding-0">
            @switch (customField.custom_field_type_id)
            {
                case Constants.CustomFieldType.checkbox:
                    foreach (var opt in customField.custom_field_options.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
                    {
                        var optValue = customField.custom_field_values.FirstOrDefault(item => item.custom_field_option_id == opt.Data.custom_field_option_id && item.custom_field_id == customField.custom_field_id);

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>@opt.Data.custom_field_option_value</label>

                    @if (optValue != null)
                    {
                        var optName = customField.custom_field_id + "_" + opt.Data.custom_field_option_id + "_" + optValue.custom_field_value_id;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="CustomFieldEdit_@opt.Data.custom_field_option_id" name="CustomFieldEdit_@optName" @(optValue.value.ToLower() == "true" ? "checked" : "") />
                        <input type="hidden" id="CustomFieldOrig_@opt.Data.custom_field_option_id" name="CustomFieldOrig_@optName" value="@optValue.value" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var optName = customField.custom_field_id + "_" + opt.Data.custom_field_option_id + "_0";
                        <input type="checkbox" id="CustomFieldEdit_@(opt.Data.custom_field_option_id)" name="CustomFieldEdit_@optName" @(opt.Data.is_checked ? "checked" : "") />
                    }
                </div>
                    }

                    break;

                         case Constants.CustomFieldType.text_input:
                    var textinputVal = customField.custom_field_values.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (textinputVal != null)
                    {
                        var textInputName = customField.custom_field_id + "_0_" + textinputVal.custom_field_value_id;
                <input type="text" id="CustomFieldEdit_@(customField.custom_field_id)" name="CustomFieldEdit_@(textInputName)" value="@textinputVal.value" class="form-control" />
                <input type="hidden" id="CustomFieldOrig_@(customField.custom_field_id)" name="CustomFieldOrig_@(textInputName)" value="@textinputVal.value" class="form-control" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var textInputName = customField.custom_field_id + "_0_0";
                <input type="text" id="CustomFieldEdit_@(customField.custom_field_id)" name="CustomFieldEdit_@(textInputName)" class="form-control" />
                    }
                    break;

            }
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Checkout a screenshot of how Visual Studio 2012 Professional formats my view code
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you were pretty good about using parentheses to escape out values so Razor wouldn't parse them as email addresses, but it looks like a few escaped having parentheses that needed them.  Try this:

```
@if (optValue != null)
{
    <input type="checkbox" id="CustomFieldEdit_@(opt.Data.custom_field_option_id)" name="CustomFieldEdit_@(customField.custom_field_id)_@(opt.Data.custom_field_option_id)_@(optValue.custom_field_value_id)" @(optValue.value.ToLower() == "true" ? "checked" : "")>
    <input type="hidden" id="CustomFieldOrig_@(opt.Data.custom_field_option_id)" name="CustomFieldOrig_@(customField.custom_field_id)_@(opt.Data.custom_field_option_id)_@(optValue.custom_field_value_id)" value="@optValue.value">
}
else
{

    <input type="checkbox" id="CustomFieldEdit_@(opt.Data.custom_field_option_id)" name="CustomFieldEdit_@(customField.custom_field_id)_@(opt.Data.custom_field_option_id)_0" @(opt.Data.is_checked ? "checked" : "")>
}
```

**Update to address updated question**

Try something like this.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>@opt.Data.custom_field_option_value</label>


    @if (optValue != null)
    {
        var optName = customField.custom_field_id + "_" + opt.Data.custom_field_option_id + "_" + optValue.custom_field_value_id;
        <input type="checkbox" id="CustomFieldEdit_@opt.Data.custom_field_option_id" name="CustomFieldEdit_@(optName)" @(optValue.value.ToLower() == "true" ? "checked" : "") />
        <input type="hidden" id="CustomFieldOrig_@opt.Data.custom_field_option_id" name="CustomFieldOrig_@(optName)" value="@(optValue.value)" />
    }
    else
    {
        var optName = customField.custom_field_id + "_" + opt.Data.custom_field_option_id + "_0";
        <input type="checkbox" id="CustomFieldEdit_@(opt.Data.custom_field_option_id)" name="CustomFieldEdit_@(optName)" @(opt.Data.is_checked ? "checked" : "") />
    }

</div>
```

**Edit for third question update**

The main issue that keeps coming up each time is that Razor mistakes certain parts of your code for legitimately formatted email addresses, however obvious to humans that they aren't.  Be sure anything that has an `@` that is immediately preceded by plain HTML/text is enclosed in parentheses.

Do:

`CustomFieldEdit_@(customField.custom_field_id)`

not

`CustomFieldEdit_@customField.custom_field_id`

(`@customField.custom_field_id` by itself would be fine, though.)

Comment: Thanks Utopia, Razor is not liking the @ in front of the if

Comment: I updated my question, I started to use @: "escape" to get farther along, still would love to know why some of my code floats left and looks ugly, not following the parent-child structure

Comment: Those lines shouldn't need the @: escape anyway, since Razor attempts to identify tags themselves.  You can also try wrapping things in the `<text>` tag if you keep having trouble.  Razor processes that as content rather than code.

Comment: That took me back to having the "Expression expected" formatting error. How do you know only the line with the input element needs escaped?

Comment: OK, I was missing a closing slash on two of my inputs, looks pretty good know, how do you know the one input element needs escaped?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't right.  I went in and pasted it all in Visual Studio and ReSharper detected your optName wasn't getting used until I put parentheses around it when you were setting your name value.  I'm suspecting it thought it was an email address again.  Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Ya it is looking better, no syntax errors, check out my latest update to my answer, it is close but I can't add an @ to my second if condition for some reason

Comment: As before, it looks like things still aren't being escaped right, indicated by variables such as `textInputName` not actually getting used.  Be sure anything that involves text being concatenated directly onto a Razor processed value (e.g. `CustomFieldEdit_@customField.custom_field_id`) has the Razor part escaped.  Otherwise, it looks like the email recipient CustomFieldEdit_ at the customField.custom_field_id domain name.

Comment: Thanks Utopia, I updated and added CustomFieldEdit_@(customField.custom_field_id) syntax everywhere, formatting still gets weird with the second case of my switch statement

Comment: Tidied up for me (VS2013) when I hit enter after pasting.

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio 2012 is lacking a little of latest Razor formatting code from Microsoft, oh well. thanks for your help